# What is the recommended HTTP status code to be used in the case of a duplicate key exception?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, api, exception, error-handling

What is the recommended HTTP status code to be utilized in a REST API when a duplicate key error is detected in MongoDB? Despite researching the issue online, a definitive answer could not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use status "409" for duplicate records.